# Function Creation in Oracle database

Tags: oracle

```
Question is : I have to Create Function with below Details 
Function Name : Credit_Limit 
Input         : Entity_Id (Shipment_entity) 
Returns       : VARCHAR2 (Limit_Status)
```

**Design rules**:

1. If the credit_limit of the given entity id is greater then 50000,then display the limit_status as 'Credit limit is greater than 50000'
2. If the credit_limit of the given entity id is less then 50000,then display the limit_status as 'Credit limit is less than 50000'

*Note: DO NOT CHANGE the given status message in your solution.*

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION credit_limit (entity_id IN INTEGER)
         RETURN VARCHAR2
       IS
         c_credit_limit   NUMBER (5, 2);
         limit_status     VARCHAR (255);
        BEGIN
          SELECT credit_limit
             INTO c_credit_limit
           FROM shipment_entity
          WHERE id = entity_id;

    IF c_credit_limit > 50000
    THEN
        limit_status := 'Credit limit is greater than 50000';
    ELSE
        IF c_credit_limit < 50000
        THEN
            limit_status := 'Credit limit is less than 50000';
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN (c_credit_limit);
    END;
    /
```

I executed the above mentioned code the function is created but it shows wrong answer after submit the code. help on this.

Comment: `number(5, 2)` will allow numbers up to `999.99`...

Comment: Better use `c_credit_limit shipment_entity.credit_limit%TYPE;` instead of `c_credit_limit NUMBER (5, 2);`

Comment: Thank you..Function is created/executed successfully

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
RETURN limit_status;
```

not

```
RETURN (c_credit_limit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Function is working fine

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION credit_limit (entity_id IN INTEGER)
         RETURN VARCHAR2
       IS
         c_credit_limit shipment_entity.credit_limit%TYPE;
         limit_status     VARCHAR (255);
        BEGIN
          SELECT credit_limit
             INTO c_credit_limit
           FROM shipment_entity
          WHERE id = entity_id;

```
IF c_credit_limit > 50000
THEN
    limit_status := 'Credit limit is greater than 50000';
ELSE
    IF c_credit_limit < 50000
    THEN
        limit_status := 'Credit limit is less than 50000';
    END IF;
END IF;

RETURN limit_status;
END;
/
```